# 3d Matrix to 2d Matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I am using Matlab R2014a.

I have a 3-dimensional M x N x M matrix A. I would like a vectorized way to extract a 2 dimensional matrix B from it, such that for each i,j I have

B(i,j)=A(i,j,g(i,j))

where g is a 2-dimensional index matrix of size M x N, i.e. with integral values in {1,2,...,M}.

The context is that I am representing a function A(k,z,k') as a 3-dimensional matrix, the function g(k,z) as a 2-dimensional matrix, and I would like to compute the function

h(k,z)=f(k,z,g(k,z))

This seems like a simple and common thing to try to do but I really can't find anything online. Thank you so much to whoever can help!

My first thought was to try something like B = A(:,:,g) or B=A(g) but neither of these works, unsurprisingly. Is there something similar?

Comment: I feel like this belongs in a matlab forum somewhere. Not too sure of the relevance to computer programming

Comment: If any of the solutions below has solved your question, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ the best tool for vectorization, [**`bsxfun`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) here -

```
B = A(bsxfun(@plus,[1:M]',M*(0:N-1)) + M*N*(g-1))
```

### Explanation: Breaking it down to two steps

**Step #1:** Calculate the indices corresponding to the first two dimensions (rows and columns) of `A` -

```
bsxfun(@plus,[1:M]',M*(0:N-1))
```

**Step #2:** Add the offset needed to include the dim-3 indices being supplied by `g` and index into A with those indices to get our desired output -

```
A(bsxfun(@plus,[1:M]',M*(0:N-1)) + M*N*(g-1))
```

---

### Benchmarking

Here's a quick benchmark test to compare this `bsxfun` based approach against the `ndgrid + sub2ind` based solution as presented in [Luis's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27339316/3293881) with `M` and `N` as `100`.

The benchmarking code using `tic-toc` would look something like this -

```
M = 100;
N = 100;
A = rand(M,N,M);
g = randi(M,M,N);

num_runs = 5000; %// Number of iterations to run each approach

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('-------------------- With BSXFUN')
tic
for iter = 1:num_runs
    B1 = A(bsxfun(@plus,[1:M]',M*(0:N-1)) + M*N*(g-1));  %//'
end
toc, clear B1

disp('-------------------- With NDGRID + SUB2IND')
tic
for iter = 1:num_runs
    [ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:M, 1:N);
    B2 = A(sub2ind([M N M], ii, jj, g));
end
toc
```

Here's the runtime results -

```
-------------------- With BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 2.090230 seconds.
-------------------- With NDGRID + SUB2IND
Elapsed time is 4.133219 seconds.
```

### Conclusions

As you can see `bsxfun` based approach works really well, both as a vectorized approach and good with performance too.

**Why is `bsxfun` better here -**

- `bsxfun` does replication of offsetted elements and adding them, both **on-the-fly**.
- In the other solution, `ndgrid` internally makes two function calls to `repmat`, thus incurring the function call overheads. At the next step, `sub2ind` spends time in adding the offsets to get the linear indices, bringing in another function call overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). This assumes `g` is defined as an `M`x`N` matrix with possible values `1`, ..., `M`:

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:M, 1:N);
B = A(sub2ind([M N M], ii, jj, g));
```