# How to get elements larger than x in a given range?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Given a matrix `A`, how do I get the elements (and their indices) larger than `x` in a specific range?

e.g.

```
A = [1:5; 2:6; 3:7; 4:8; 5:9]

A =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9
```

And for instance I want all elements larger than 5 and appear in the range `A(2:4,3:5)`. I should get:

elements:

```
6 , 6 , 7 , 6 , 7 , 8
```

indices:

```
14, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24
```

`A(A>5)` would give me all entries which are larger than 5.

`A(2:4,3:5)` would give all elements in the range `2:4,3:5`.

I want some combination of the two. Is it possible or the only way is to put the needed range in another array `B` and only then perform `B(B>5)`? Obviously 2 problems here: I'd lose the original indices, and it will be slower. I'm doing this on a large number of matrices.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/2647279. So the answer is no, unless you use some ugly hacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code.** I'm trying to avoid matrix multiplication, so this may look a bit odd:

```
A = [1:5; 2:6; 3:7; 4:8; 5:9];

[r,c] = meshgrid(2:4,3:5);
n     = sub2ind(size(A), r(:), c(:));

indices = sort(n(A(n) > 5)); %'skip sorting if not needed'
values  = A(indices);
```

**Explanation.** The code converts the Cartesian product of the subscripts to linear indices in the `A` matrix. Then it selects the indices that respect the condition, then it selects the values.

However, it is slow.

**Optimization.** Following [LuisMendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo)'s suggestion, the code may be sped up by replacing the `sub2ind`-based linear index calculation with a handcrafted linear index calculation:

```
A = [1:5; 2:6; 3:7; 4:8; 5:9];

%'For column-first, 1-based-index array memory   '
%'layout, as in MATLAB/FORTRAN, the linear index '
%'formula is:                                    '
%'L = R + (C-1)*NR                               '
n = bsxfun(@plus, (2:4), (transpose(3:5) - 1)*size(A,1)); 

indices = n(A(n) > 5);
values  = A(indices);
```

Comment: Wow! So fast! 2.5 times faster than using a temporary matrix!

Comment: And sorting is not needed.

Comment: Possibly faster: `n = bsxfun(@plus, (2:4), ((3:5).'-1)*size(A,1));` instead of `meshgrid` and `sub2ind`

Comment: @LuisMendo - Yes! faster by 2 seconds

Comment: @LuisMendo It's a good idea indeed to replace the two expensive calls of `meshgrid` and `subs2ind` with handcrafted linear index calculation.

Comment: @AlaaM. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27341488/3293881) a benchmark comparison on `meshgrid/ndgrid + sub2ind` vs `bsxfun` for a related problem and few insights into the possible reasons on better performance with `bsxfun` .

Answer (score 2):

*If you only need the values* (not the indices), it can be done using the third output of `find` and matrix multiplication. I don't know if it will be faster than using a temporary array, though:

```
[~, ~, values] = find((A(2:4,3:5)>5).*A(2:4,3:5));
```

Assuming *you need the linear indices and the values*, then *if the threshold is positive* you could define a mask. This may be a good idea if the mask can be defined once and reused for all matrices (that is, if the desired range is the same for all matrices):

```
mask = false(size(A));
mask(2:4,3:5) = true;
indices = find(A.*mask>5);
values = A(indices);
```

Comment: The indices are actually more important. I'll look into the answer though. Thanks

Comment: How about making the `mask` sparse? It might help with memory problems if there's small test "windows".

Comment: @CST-Link Good idea for memory efficiency! As for speed I'm not so sure

Answer (score 0):

its a little clunky, but:

```
R = 2:4;
C = 3:5;
I = reshape(find(A),size(A))

indicies = nonzeros(I(R,C).*(A(R,C)>5))
values = A(indicies)
```

Comment: Does this give the indices?